# ZF2 Route Parameter name changed on controller

Tags: php, routes, zend-framework2

I am creating a Zend Framework 2 application and i have the following routes:

- customer

  - default
  - modifycustomercategoryform - /:controller/:action/:CustomerCategoryId
  - deletecustomercategoryform - /:controller/:action/:CustomerCategoryId
  - modifyleadsourceform - /:controller/:action/:LeadSourceId
  - deleteleadsourceform - /:controller/:action/:LeadSourceId

I build the link in a view script and I click the link; I go to the right Controller/Action however, I get the parameter sent as LeadSourceId

I am doing a var_dump

```
 $params1 = $this->getEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParams();
 $id = $this->params()->fromRoute('LeadSourceId');
 var_dump($params1, $id);
```

The values displayed are :

```
array(5) {
    ["__NAMESPACE__"]  => string(19) "Customer\Controller"
    ["controller"]     => string(36) "Customer\Controller\CustomerCategory"
    ["action"]         => string(29) "modify-customer-category-form"
    ["LeadSourceId"]   => string(1) "1"
    ["__CONTROLLER__"] => string(16) "CustomerCategory"
    } string(1) "1"
```

I will appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction.

I thought it could be some cache issue and I restarted my browser & apache still no solution

Comment: So the wrong route is being matched? If you visit `/somecontroller/someaction/1` how is ZF2 going to know which route should be matched?

Comment: I am getting the right controller/action -> This controller and action is only in one route with a parameter

Comment: did u create two different controller for customercategory, and leadsource ?

Comment: Yes, the pattern for both the routers are the same; they have a different default value basically the controller and action name and different and the parameter name is different;
Is it a good practice to define routers like this; basically routematch can give anything and that is probably what is happening. 
I removed all the routes and created 2 routes one default and another with parameters. It is working and the parameter passed is "id1"